# Match last occurrence of ”

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string that might look like this:

```
<p>“bla bla bla “Another THing”,more text to the sentence.”</p>
```

I'm looking to match the last `”` character and wrap it with a span. The first one is easy:

```
var str = '<p>“bla bla bla “Another THing”,more text to the sentence.”</p>'
str.replace(/“/,"<span class=quote>“</span>")
```

but since there may be a few closing `”` in the sentence, how do I match just the last one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use look ahead:

```
str = str.replace(/”(?=[^”]*$)/,"<span class=quote>”</span>")
```

This will replace a `"` which is followed by a sequence of `non-"` characters till the end.

Comment: Worked great -thats a lot, didn't know about the look ahead.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm... how about

```
var astr = str.Split("“");

astr[astr.length-2] += "<span class=quote>";
astr[astr.length-1] = "</span>" + astr[astr.length-1];

str = astr.join("“");
```

fun but fails if you don't have any `“` -- so error checking is advised.

No idea if it is faster than a look ahead regex -- but now you got options.